# How do I tell iOS 7 which address is my “home” address?

Tags: contacts, ios, notifications, siri

In iOS 7, if you bring up the Notification Center in some circumstances it will tell you, “Right now, it would take you 18 minutes to drive home.” I recently moved and the address that iOS 7 has set as “home” is now incorrect, but I still want to include the old address in my contact card. How do I inform Siri (and the rest of the system) that my “home” address has changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

- Edit your contact card on your phone (in the Contacts application);
- Change the label of your old address to anything you want;
- Set the label of your new address to "home"