# Changing my home address in iOS 7 not picked up in Maps or notification center

Tags: ios, notifications, contacts, maps

I need to change my home address, following [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105506/how-do-i-tell-ios-7-which-address-is-my-home-address). I've moved, so I need to update my address, but it does not seem to work. My new street address does not exist in the map (as I've moved to a newly developed area), and when changing the address in my contact, the old address is still recognized as "Home" in my Maps application. (Thus, also displaying "Right now, it would take you XX mins to drive home" to my old address) Does anyone know how I can correct this?

Comment: Only the contacts card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to clear the map history from Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services -> System Services -> Frequent Locations. Doing this, changing my contact card and updating my AppleID seem to have solved the problem (Apart from the fact that my street doesn't exist yet).

Comment: Did this, shut off my phone and restarted, now there's no location at all on the "Right now, it would take you XX mins to drive home" screen. Maybe it takes some time to update?

Comment: As far as I can remember, it took some time for it to update throughout :)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely update your details on your Apple ID.

1. Go to [AppleID](https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/)
2. Update your address details
3. You should be done

The fact that your street does not exist in Apple Maps is nothing you can do about, except leaving feedback at Apple so they can update their map to be consistent.

Regarding the "home" location in your contact, you have to edit the one with **me** next to it. Also please check if you have yourself multiple times listed (iCloud, local, other sources).

I've just changed my location to check it and my **Home** is now changed as you stated in your question.

Comment: Does not seem to do the trick :( I've tried updating both contact card and AppleID as well as clearing maps search logs. Still holds on to the old "Home" location.

Comment: My AppleID is tied to a PO box, so this doesn't work for me. I have both my physical home address and the PO box in the "me" contact info, but it doesn't seem to be able to find "home".

Answer (score -1):

On iPhone 7 go to map settings: change house number, city, state and zip. Pretty easy actually. Went to Samsung 7... so excited to get an iPhone again❤️

Comment: The OP was asking how to do this on iOS 7, not the iPhone 7.  The iPhone 7, I believe, can't even run iOS 7.